# When debugging Vue app in Safari, Firebase Auth change handlers are not triggered

Tags: vue.js, firebase-authentication, safari, pinia

NOTE: This issue does not occur in Chrome at any point or in Safari production.

Inside my pinia store, I have this code:

```
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (newUser) => {
    user.value = newUser
    if (newUser) {
      user.value = newUser

      router.push({ name: 'content' })
    } else {
      router.push({ name: 'login' })
    }
  })
```

Here is the method that is called to login in the pinia store:

```
  async function loginGoogle() {
    nProgress.start()
    if (!user.value) {
      await setPersistence(auth, inMemoryPersistence)
      await signInWithRedirect(auth, provider)
    }
    nProgress.done()
  }
```

This is where the login call is made:

```
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  NProgress.start()
  document.title = to.meta.title as string
  if (to.meta.requiresAuth) {
    const userStore = useAuthStore()
    const user = userStore.user
    if (!user) {
      router.push({ name: 'login' })
    }
    next()
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
```

As expected in Chrome and Safari (production only), when clicking on a button that navigates to a page requiring authentication, the login screen appears. Once you user signs in, then the router automatically navigates to the content page.
However, in Safari (development), once the user logs in, nothing happens, it stays on the login screen.

Answer (score 0):

for checking if a user is logged in and therefore gets access to routes with `requiresAuth` i would handle with a login state. i'll write you here an example how the function `onAuthStateChange` could look like.

```js
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (newUser) => {
        user.value = newUser
        if (newUser) {
          user.value = newUser
          // handle the login state here
          this.isLoggedIn = true
    
          // dont use router inside pinia
          router.push({ name: 'content' })
        } else {
          router.push({ name: 'login' })
        }
      })
```

your function now has a state `isloggedIn`, but of course you have to define it as a state first.
with this state you can check if the user has a logged in session or not and display your content accordingly.

your router push has actually lost nothing in this function. try it like this:

```html
    <div v-if="authStore.isLoggedIn" >
      <router-view />
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <router-view name="auth" />
    </div>
```

for this you have to define another named route for your `requiredAuth`.

Now you just have it exactly like this:
If the user is logged in I use the default router-view, if not then the name="auth" router-view.

an example of a routeGuard that works in this case:

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const authStore = useAuthStore()
  if (authStore.isLoggedIn && to.path === '/') {
    next('/content')
    return
  }
  if (!authStore.isLoggedIn && to.path !== '/login') {
    next('/')
    return
  } else {
    next()
    return
  }
})
```

this architectural approach is cleaner.
i hope this might solve your problem. if not let's move on.